# django accessing errors

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following:

```
{% if formDetails.errors %}
{% for key, value in formDetails.errors.items %}
{% for error in value %}
    <div class="ui-widget" id="id-error">
        <div class="ui-state-error ui-corner-all" style="padding: 0 .7em;">
            <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>
            <strong>{{ key }}:</strong> {{ error }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But unfortunately `key` gives me the name of the model field (the one that's lowercase with underscores). How can I get the nice looking name like `field.label_tag`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `form.errors` template variable is a list not a dictionary, so you should access it as follows:

```
{% for error in form.errors %}
    <li>{{ error }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

In addition it contains form wide errors raised by the `clean()` method on the `Form` object you are dealing with. Validation errors raised by the individual fields, can be accessed like this:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {% for error in field.errors %}
        {{ error }}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ field.label_tag }}
{% endfor %}
```

Have a read of [this part of the Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields), it seems like you don't have a full understanding of what you have when accessing a form.

Comment: Your second example works fine. Cheers! Now I have the errors above the form you don't happen to know how to stop the errors appearing above the individual fields?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't use `as_table` if you want to remove the error message from above the fields as I found out from the link above :(

Comment: The errors for each field are specific to **each** field. You can vary where things are displayed by using the supplied tags and for loops etc. as described in my answer and the supplied docs.