# django how to access first error in a list of error messages

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, django-errors

So suppose I have a form called form and I want to display on the screen only the first error message, if there exists error messages. I did some research and apparently you can access just the first error message by typing this in the template.

```
{{ form.errors.0 }}
```

but it doesn't seem to work for me, it doesn't display anything. How do I make my template so that it displays just the first error message if there are form errors? Here is what I tried.

```
<html>
    <body>

    <form method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
    </form>

    {% if form.errors %}
            {{ form.errors.0 }}
        {% endif %}
    </body>
</html>
```

So, what I want is, I want to display only the first error in {{form.errors}}.
Note that when I change

```
{{ form.errors.0 }}
```

to

```
{{ form.errors }}
```

it does display all of the errors, however, I only want to display one error, just the First error message. So, any idea why my dot notation isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form.errors is not a dictionary, at least according to other related questions in StackOverflow:

[django accessing errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770537/django-accessing-errors)

[django: how to access only first error message in form.errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950079/django-how-to-access-only-first-error-message-in-form-errors)

If you really need to get only first error (remembering that all field errors will come together), you can try to convert to values and then get the first item, like:

```
{{form.errors.values.0}}
```

or

```
{{form.errors.items.0}}
```

This second will return a tuple with label and error message.

Comment: okay great.. so {{ form.errors }} displays the field and then the error message. For example, if a user didn't fill in the username field, it would display "username - This field is required". But when I do {{ form.errors.items.0 }} it just displays the error message. Is there a way to display the field name as well? I know the tuple returns with the error message but the tuple doesn't look good, it looks like "('username',[u'This field is required.'])" Is there any way to change how it looks? Also, can I have a like as to where you learned the {{ form.errors.values.0}} from?

Comment: Oh okay what I did was {% if form.errors %} {% for errors in form.errors %} {% if forloop.counter == 1 %} {{ errors }} {% endif %} {% endfor %} {{ form.errors.values.0 }} {% endif %}.. that way, it display "username - This field is required".. but yea, thanks a lot! It would also be great if you can send me a link to where you learned the {{form.errors.values.0}} and {{form.errors.items.0}} from :)

Comment: I just tried both as this is an extended dicionary:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/utils.py#L41
When you call without a method, it turns in this "as_ul", look the __str__ method

Comment: Ah okay, so I can just change that __str__ method right? okay perfect, thanks! Also, you said "When you call without a method".. call what without a method?

Comment: {{ form.errors }} you call __str__ method by default, and {{form.errors.0}} too. But {{form.errors.copy}}, for instance, you call a dict copy, then you're calling a method from the ErrorDict class.

Comment: hm oh okay interesting.